# AWK getline example , please explain the output?

Tags: bash, awk

I found this `awk` example with **getline** but not able to understand how it works.

```
seq 5 | awk 'BEGIN { getline; print "Read ahead first line", $0 } {print $0 }'
```

The output is:

```
Read ahead first line 1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Thanks Sundeep for editing the question

Comment: you're welcome... see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for future use... also, you could mark whichever answer helped you best...

Answer (score 2):

`seq 5` produces

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

`awk`'s `BEGIN` block is executed before the main block.
`getline` reads a line, which is printed in the `BEGIN` block as `$0`.
Then the main block reads the remaining lines.

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'BEGIN { getline; print "BEGIN read", $0} {print "main read", $0 }'
BEGIN read 1
main read 2
main read 3
main read 4
main read 5
```

Comment: Confusion was with getline and print $0 in in Begin. Thanks for your answer. Its quite useful @molbdnilo

Answer (score 1):

```
seq 5 | awk 'BEGIN { getline; print "Read ahead first line", $0 } {print $0 }'
```

seq 5 you will get

```
$ seq 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

and from `BEGIN { getline; print "Read ahead first line", $0 }`, awk will read first record from `stdin`  thats is `1`

Through pipe `seq 5 | awk '{...}'` ( `first program | second program` )
**Pipes are used to redirect a stream from one program to another. When a program's standard output is sent to another through a pipe**

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'BEGIN { getline; print "Read ahead first line", $0 }'
Read ahead first line 1
```

and `{print $0 }` after BEGIN block will read remaining records that is 2 to 5, here is how without printing inside `BEGIN` block

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'BEGIN { getline} {print $0}'
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: @rachnagarg although Akshay explaining the semantics of that code well, I just want to make sure it's clear you would **never** actually write that code. If you're ever considering using `getline` then make sure to read and fully understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first.